# What is the etymology of берлога?

Tags: этимология

I am wondering why the shelter of *медведь* is *берлога*.

Comment: Are you sure your question is about linguistics and not about animal behaviour? It is similar to the question why birds live in nests and bees in a hive.

Comment: @YellowSky I think that there's a certain degree of similarity between the "бер" in "берлога" to the english word "bear". The rest of the word comes from "логово" :):):)

Comment: That's not so, "берлога" and "bear" are not connected. The word is found in most Slavic languages and has cognates in Lithuanian, it origianlly meant "dirt", "hey underlay". Look it up in any etymological dictionary.

Comment: @YellowSky, obviously, he is joking. :)

Comment: Ну ладно, а `тигр` это so called *loan-translation* of `tiger`? И дальше, `Сибирь` это калька с `Siberia`? А что это за местность си**Бер**ия такая? Это там, где водятся те самые *беры*? В русском (в России) что, все свои названия взяты из латинского и английского? А не наоборот ли? Это просто к размышлению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Берлога - диал. мерлога, мерлуга - то же, русск.-цслав. бьрлогъ, укр.
>   берлога "соломенная подстилка, скверная постель", болг. бърлок "мусор,
>   мутные помои", сербохорв. брлог "свинарник, логово, мусорная свалка",
>   брльог – то же, словен. brlog, род. brloga "пещера, убежище", чеш.
>   brloh "логово, хибара", польск. barog, род. -ogu "соломенная
>   подстилка, мусор, нечистоты", в.-луж. boroh, н.-луж. barog "соломенная
>   подстилка". Вместе с сербохорв. брљати "путать, пачкать", брљага
>   "лужа", болг. бърлок "лужа" эти слова, по-видимому, связаны с лит.
>   burlas "грязь, кал", burlungis "топкое место"; Еще более сомнительны
>   др. предположения: против объяснения сложением с -logъ см. Ягич, там
>   же. Столь же ошибочно пытались выделить в этом слове bьr-, якобы
>   родственное нем. Bar "медведь", др.-инд. bhallas, bhallakas "медведь",
>   лит. beras "коричневый".

[Фасмер М.](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vasmer.php?id=159&vol=1)

> БЕРЛОГА, -и, ж. —«зимнее логовище медведя»; (иногда) «место зимней
>   спячки другого зверя». Укр. (из польск.) барлiг, род. барлoга —
>   «берлога» и «грязная лужа», «грязь»; блр. бярлог, ж.—«берлога»,
>   «логово»; словен. brlog — «берлога», «логово зверя»; чеш. и словац.
>   brloh — «берлога»; польск. bartog — «берлога», «(смятая соломенная)
>   подстилка». Из русского — болг. бърлoга — тж. (но ср. по говорам
>   бърлог — «мусор», «помои»). в.-луж. borto, ср. — «смятая грязная
>   подстилка», «логово», также «лужа», «залив»; н.-луж. bartog — «смятая
>   грязная солома». Др.-рус. (XII в.) бьрлогъ ( :бьрлога, ж.?) —
>   «логово». Старославянскими (балканского происхождения) памятниками
>   слово берлога не засвидетельствовано. □ В этимологическом отношении не
>   вполне ясное, спорное слово. Учитывая, однако, значение этого
>   (очевидно, сложного, с двумя основами) слова, можно полагать, что оно
>   восходит к о.-с. •bьrlogъ [относительно -log-ъ ср. рус. логово (см.
>   лежать)]. По первой части сложения это о.-с. слово связано, с одной
>   стороны, с др.-рус. бьрние — «грязь», «глина».

[П. Я. Черных. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка](http://chernykh-etym.narod.ru/t1/p086.htm)

So, it's connected with some word that means "dirt, feces, garbage". And not with bear

Answer (score 3):

In the religion of the ancient Indo-Europeans the word for a bear was tabooed because this animal induced fear.

The most ancient Indo-European word for bear was ***a̯rtcos*** which meant "destructor". As the word was tabooed, it was replaced by a word meaning "brown", a derivative of the PIE ***bhrua̯nos*** "brown". It is the source of the English word "bear" and "бер-", the first part in "берлога". The second part meant "lair" and the derivative of the Proto-Indo-European ***leghos*** "lair, bed". Thus "берлога" means "bear's lair"

But the word "бер" became tabooed again and was replaced by a new word "медведь" which meant "honey-eater". It derives from the ***medhu***, a Proto-Indo European word for mead, a drink produced from honey (honey is called мёд in Russian) and the root ***e̯ed-*** "to eat".

Comment: could you please source the connection between *+-bʰer-* and *берлога*? No elymologic dictionary seems to agree with that.

Comment: @Quassnoi it is not connected to the root -bher-

Comment: that's how my dictionary lists the root for "brown". The adjective would be *bʰruh2nos* I believe, through the ablaut.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, поискал про медведя и берлогу - оказалось очень интересно.

---

**БЕР ("Бе + Ръ")** В разных словах этот корень раскрывается разными гранями своего объемного смысла. В одном из значений раньше этим словом называли "медведя" (отсюда в языке сохранилось слово "берлога" как "медвежье логово" или как "медведя силовое основание движения"). А еще это - одно из имен бога Велеса (его же именовали еще Святибором) и значит "рожденный". Отсюда слово "беременность". Родственные слова: БЕРег, БЕРкут, ЦерБЕР, БЕРеза и т.д. ... После утраты подлинных смыслов в обиходе остались два взаимосвязанных, но разнородных слова: "берлога" и "медведь".

---

Слово "Медведь" составлено из двух основ "Мёд" и "Ведать", таким образом, медведь - ведающий в мёде.
Но слово "Медведь" не являлось истинным именем этого животного, его использовали все: женщины, ремесленники, дети.
Истинное же имя не использовали из суеверия, боясь позвать страшное животное. 
Им пользовались только охотники. По всей видимости, оно звучало как "бер", т.е. "тот, кто берёт". В европейских языках оно и сейчас используется - "bear" в английском, "baer" в немецом. В русском же осталось слово "берлога" - ложе бера.

---

кстати, интересное явление: английский и немецкий языки, оказывается, гораздо дальше от латыни, ибо в английском -"bear" , в немецком "baer", а по-латински медведь: ursus

---

Так-то. А вы говорите, мусор, нечистоты.
П.С Со словами цербер и беременность я лично не не согласен, они здесь не к месту и к беру не относятся

Comment: В википедии хорошо написано про [этимологию слова медведь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B8#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.8C:_.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B1.D1.83). Bear - такой же эвфемизм как и "мед ведает".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_etymology

Comment: Вот не даёт мне покоя эта берлога. Википедия основывается на [статье словаря Фасмера](http://goo.gl/AUkTeK), где про версию о логове бера говорится: *Неубедительно также предположение Ягича...*. То есть, не утверждается, что оно ошибочно, и допускается, что оно может быть верно. В [других](http://goo.gl/adtnWP) [этимологических](http://goo.gl/BJtY3J) [словарях](http://goo.gl/jcr6o6) это всё-таки логово.

Comment: А про False_etymology замечу, что соответствующей русской статьи на вики даже нет. Ложная этимология в английском - намного бОльшая проблема, из-за его высокой связности. Видели кроссворды на английском, где слова в нескольких рядах и колонках без промежутков? На русском такие составлять очень сложно, потому что слова не такие компактные и содержат больше информации. Поэтому в русском языке легче вычислить верную этимологию слова, а в Википедии нет статьи о ложной этимологии (последнее - шутка, если кто не понял)

Comment: Беременность is probably related. It is derived from бремя which means a burden (one of the rare meanings is a birth), i.e. something to carry, or to bear (bʰer-).

Answer (score 0):

Fasmer is far too old. He did not believe берлога could come from the *bher-, that gave English bear. But he was wrong. Берлога certainly is логово bher'а. Reasons are given. And... actually бурый comes from the same root.

Comment: Fasmer is not too old. The idea of "логово бера" was popular long before his works.

Comment: @Artemix: he's Vasmer, FWIW

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, you are right. I just wanted to make sure that we are talking about the same man though :)

Comment: The idea had already existed before him, but since then new experience and hypotheses of linguists restated the idea and proved it - as far as anything in the indo-european linguistic can be proved, of course.

Comment: *bhr-uanos comes from *bher with "zero ablaut grade". Actually everything is written above my post by Anixx

Answer (score 0):

C учетом того что, медведи часто (в далеком прошлом, хотя случается и ныне) выходили к людям и копались в их, человеческом, мусоре в поисках пропитания, вполне основано можно предположить:
берлога - логово коричневого-грязного-мусорного

Comment: Для того чтобы привязать медведя к бурому цвету вовсе не обязательно заставлять его "часто копаться в человеческом мусоре". И, кстати, эта версия уже есть в ответах.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that it's connected with slavic word бер, that means "bear" itself. Plus the russian word логово, so it can be interpreted as логово бера.

Comment: You suppose, or are there sources? And welcome to RL&U.SE, by the way.

Comment: In which Slavic language the word "бер" that means "bear" is used?

Comment: Does Берлин in Germany has anything to do with bears?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- - The origin of the name Berlin is unknown, but it may have its roots in the language of West Slavic inhabitants of the area of today's Berlin, and be related to the Old Polabian stem berl-/birl- ("swamp"). Folk etymology connects it to the German Bär, a bear, and a bear appears in the coat of arms of the city. [From here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin#Etymology).

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73-: no, but Berlin is most probably connected to *берлога*, both are believed to derive from PS *+бьрлъ* "mud, swamp, puddle".

Answer (score -3):

Медведь - бурый. Так   его называли. Отсюда бер в значении бурый.

Comment: So cheesy. If you want to promote Russian culture, give an answer backed by fact and science, not emotion.